# SQL Function check if a date is between 2 dates from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I am using a function which currently calculates the SLA between two dates passed in, this checks for NULL items and returns 0.

I now need to take into account the dates inside a new table 'NonBusinessDays' and take these off the total SLA value.

How would I check if the two passed in values contain any dates between their range from the other tables dates, if they do they need to take off that date from the SLA total.

Currently the table sits like;

```
CREATE TABLE #NonBusinessDays(
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO #NonBusinessDays
           ([id]
           ,[date]
           ,[name]
           ,[type])
     VALUES
           ('1DF6A335-56F8-4DA7-B9C3-07DBAC9FBA8D'
           ,'2019-08-26'
           ,'Summer bank holiday'
           ,'PublicHoliday')

           ('0940FDC9-A875-48C5-BED8-0ABFA3AA5AE8',
            '2018-05-07',
            'Early May bank holiday',
            'PublicHoliday')
GO
```

So my Function is like this;

```
CREATE FUNCTION dateSLA
(
@date1 DATETIME,
@date2 DATETIME
)
returns INT
AS 
BEGIN

declare @days INT
set @days = 0

      IF @date1 IS NULL AND @date2 IS NULL
            BEGIN
            GOTO Final
      END
      ELSE IF @date1 IS NOT NULL AND @date2 IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN


            SET @days = DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, @date1, 103), CONVERT(DATE, @date2, 103))

            GOTO Final
      END

Final:

return @days

END
GO
```

I would like it to check if any dates inside the NonBusinessDays Table are present between the parameters passed into the Function then it would take however many days off the SLA.

Example, if two dates from the BusinessDays exist between the passed in the parameters then this would take 2 off. So the SLA calcualted at 10 but this would make it 8 due to 2 non-business days were present.

Any guidance would be appreciated, if you require any more information please let me know and I will amend.

Comment: Can whoever decided to model non business days be persuaded to instead have a full calendar table (I mean, come one, 20 years worth of data is still less than 10000 rows)? Then you could just run a `COUNT(*)` against this table for all days that fall between your two dates and which are marked as working days.

Comment: Unfortunately in this instance it cannot be changed, this database is owned by a developer to which I just have to work with... I know... not the normal situation but I have to compromise and use what option I have.

I'm not after anyone to write this out for me specifically just after a little guidance do I need to pull in all of the dates into a temp table first and then compare afterwards or is there something smarter which someone can point me in the direction towards :)

Comment: its been a long time since i seen the goto statement. Is this still not exterminated ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reduce this function considerably and take into account the non working days:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dateSLA
(
@date1 DATETIME,
@date2 DATETIME
)
returns INT
AS 
BEGIN

return COALESCE(
  DATEDIFF(day,@date1,@date2) -
  (select COUNT(*) from #NonBusinessDays
   where date between CAST(@date1 as date) and CAST(@date2 as date)),
  0)

END
GO
```

If either `@date1` or `@date2` is `null` then the `datediff` will return `null`, the subtraction will leave `null` and finally the coalesce turns this into a `0`.

`DATEDIFF` counts *boundaries* There are just as many day boundaries (transitions at midnight) between two `datetime`s and the same values with the time portion removed. So we don't need them as `date`s for the `DATEDIFF` call. We do need such for matching a non-working day on the start date, so we retain the `CAST` there, and also because of the data type mismatch and for symmetry we do the same for the end date.

I'm ignoring what happens when `@date2` is less than `@date1`, which is presumably an invalid input to this function anyway.

As I said in a comment, I'd prefer a full calendar table here where we could just do the `COUNT(*)` operation against the working days, but understand it's not an option at this time for you. (At which point you start questioning the need for a function at all)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, you are correct the application determines the validation where date2 cannot be less than date1. I will look into the answer provided and run it through a couple of test to see how it works so I can better understand it for next time I come across something like this. I would prefer a calendar table as there are plenty of other reason this would be used so I will be challenging the design in our next meeting - I will comment back shortly.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for the guidance and explanation. I've had a look and I have linked up the DB to another new Analysis DB where I can host a Calendar table 
 in the interim. Before I model this, would you happen to have any tips on the layout of this table?